# I cannot find the Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item. \end{frame}

Tags: beamer

I cannot getting the erros in this code and facing "Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item. \end{frame}" problem. The file given in this

```
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Possible sources of UHE cosmic neutrinos}
\begin{itemize}
\graphicspath{{C:/Users/hhh/Desktop/Diagram/}}
\begin{figure}[h!]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{blazarneutrino.jpg}
    \caption{The accelareted protons at AGN jets interact with the ambiant photons or matter producing UHE neutrinos}
    \end{figure}
    \item \paragraph{\color{red}AGNs:} 
    \begin{equation}
     p+\gamma\rightarrow \Delta^+\rightarrow n+\pi^+\:\: ; p+X\rightarrow         \pi^\pm+Y
    \end{equation}
    \item leading to the production of UHE neutrinos through:
    \begin{equation}
    \begin{aligned}{}&
    \pi^+\rightarrow\mu^++\nu_\mu \:,\pi^-\rightarrow \mu^-+ \overline{\nu_\mu}\:,\mu^+\rightarrow e^++\overline{\nu_\mu}+\nu_e\\&
  \mu^-\rightarrow e^-+\nu_\mu+\overline{\nu_e}\:,\pi^0\rightarrow 2\gamma
    \end{aligned}
    \end{equation} 
    \end{itemize}

    \end{frame}
```

After making this

```
  \begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Possible sources of UHE cosmic neutrinos}
  \graphicspath{{C:/Users/SATYABRATA/Desktop/Diagram/}}
  \begin{figure}[h!]
   \centering
  \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{blazarneutrino.jpg}
  \caption{The accelareted protons at AGN jets interact with the ambiant     photons or matter producing UHE neutrinos}
  \end{figure}
  \begin{itemize}
  \item \paragraph{\color{red}AGNs:} 
  \begin{equation}
   p+\gamma\rightarrow \Delta^+\rightarrow n+\pi^+\:\: ; p+X\rightarrow    \pi^\pm+Y
   \end{equation}
  \item leading to the production of UHE neutrinos through:
  \begin{equation}
  \begin{aligned}{}&
  \pi^+\rightarrow\mu^++\nu_\mu \:,\pi^-\rightarrow \mu^-+\overline{\nu_      \mu}\:,\mu^+\rightarrow e^++\overline{\nu_\mu}+\nu_e\\&
  \mu^-\rightarrow e^-+\nu_\mu+\overline{\nu_e}\:,\pi^0\rightarrow 2\gamma
    \end{aligned}
    \end{equation} 
   \end{itemize}
   \end{frame}
```

It shows the same problem now "Undefined control sequence. \end{frame}"

Comment: Does `\begin{figure}[h!]` begin with `\item`?

Comment: Giving this '\item' reduces one error but Undefined control sequence. '\end{frame}' remains

Comment: What makes you think that `\item\paragraph{text}` is good? It isn't.

Comment: Thank u @egreg.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to move the figure out of the `itemize` environment.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Possible sources of UHE cosmic neutrinos}
\begin{figure}[h!]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image-duck}
    \caption{The accelareted protons at AGN jets interact with the ambiant photons or matter producing UHE neutrinos}
    \end{figure}
\begin{itemize}
    \item \textcolor{red}{AGNs}:
    \begin{equation}
     p+\gamma\rightarrow \Delta^+\rightarrow n+\pi^+\:\: ; p+X\rightarrow         \pi^\pm+Y
    \end{equation}
    \item leading to the production of UHE neutrinos through:
    \begin{equation}
    \begin{aligned}{}&
    \pi^+\rightarrow\mu^++\nu_\mu \:,\pi^-\rightarrow \mu^-+ \overline{\nu_\mu}\:,\mu^+\rightarrow e^++\overline{\nu_\mu}+\nu_e\\&
  \mu^-\rightarrow e^-+\nu_\mu+\overline{\nu_e}\:,\pi^0\rightarrow 2\gamma
    \end{aligned}
    \end{equation} 
    \end{itemize}

    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: OK ITS WORKING ,THANKS

Comment: sorry my problem remains

Comment: @DarkKnight45 You need to replace `\paragraph{\color{red}AGNs:}` by `\textcolor{red}{QGNs:}` (which I did in my code and has meanwhile also been mentioned by egreg).

Comment: Thank u @marmot